# error when using RSS feed webpart in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, rss

I'm using the RSS webpart to display an RSS feed. It worked fine for 2 years, but a couple months ago it stopped working and displays the error message 'The requested RSS feed could not be displayed. Please verify the settings and url for this feed. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator.' I have used other RSS readers to try the feed and it displays fine.

I'm the site admin in the 'I am responsible for this website' way, not the 'I am the server admin in the IT department' way so I can't check the logs or do anything server-side, which is frustrating. The RSS feed is hosted on the same top-level domain as the Sharepoint site and both URLs force HTTPS. From Googling the error I have a hunch it has something to do with either a proxy server or security issues relating to the cert. I've sent links to the server admin but they're dragging their feet and I'm starting to wonder if they don't know what's wrong and I want to find something I can send to the server admin, because if I don't, this is going to turn into a 'ignore it and hope it goes away' problem on their part.